# NullPointerException when accessing a null value that setted using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, hibernate-mapping

I set null value to an int field in MySQL database table using hibernate.

Here in the POJO class I declared the property type as `Integer`(Because if it is `int` , I cannot save to database).Also in hibernate mapping file I changed the property type to `integer`.

Thus save works fine.

But when I am trying to retrieve that null value(from bean using get method) in JSP page, I am getting `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Could you paste your code?

Comment: My Exception is 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /userEdit.jsp at line 36

33:           fname=user.getFname ();
34:           lname=user.getLname ();
35:           
36:           salary=user.getSalary ();
37:         %>
38:

Comment: Never. I am getting  fname=user.getFname () and lname=user.getLname() correctly as they have values in database. But salary=user.getSalary(); where salary field is null in database. and getting NullPointException.